# mysql query unable to update

Tags: php, mysqli

```
Mysqli query not updating table with custid
    // Create connection
            $db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if (!$db) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

    //$query = "Select expiry from AcctSession where id ='$id' ";
     echo $custid.$id; //works fine here

     $query = "update sessions SET custid = '$custid' where id = '$id' ";

            if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
            }
```

I've tried echoing $query
Query works fine on command line but it doesn't write any result when firing from php script(Plus, no error msg as well)

Comment: you should also check `->affected_rows` as well, you can have a successful query without any changes

Comment: No error in the logs either? And are you sure $custid and $id are sane? As written, the code is open to SQL injection if an attacker includes single quotes in $custid or $id. Anyway, a possible problem is that one of them may come with invisible characters that don't show when output. Displaying the query with e.g. urlencode() would help find if that's the case.

Comment: i am not concerned about sql injections right now but thatnk you

Comment: i tried affected rows, result comes out with 0 rows effected but the query is right !!

Comment: If affected_rows is 0, either the given id does not exist in that table, or the value is already the given one. To distinguish the case, use mysqli_info. If the id does not exist but it should, try dumping the query with urlencode() as I suggested above.

Comment: info says matched = 0..but the id is present in the table

Comment: the id used is 32bit long..does that make a difference??